# Sending mails in PHP using Yahoo SMTP

Tags: php

How can I send an email via *Yahoo!*'s SMTP servers in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). The following example is for Swift:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Your subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')
;

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password')
;

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's built-in [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function to send mails, however it is generally very limited. For instance, I don't think you can use other SMTP servers than the one specified in your php.ini file.

Instead you should take a look at the [Mail PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/). For example:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
$to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "mail.example.com";
$username = "smtp_username";
$password = "smtp_password";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

(I stole this example from http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm :P)

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP mailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) will let you use any SMTP server you like, so long as you have the credentials to log on with.