# want to send mails from php using yahoo smtp

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending mails in php using yahoo smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512021/sending-mails-in-php-using-yahoo-smtp)

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

$mail->Host = "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com";

$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port

$mail->Username = "sumthing@yahoo.com";

$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From = "sumthing@yahoo.com";

$mail->FromName = "myname";

$mail->AddAddress("you@example.com");

$mail->Subject = "Test PHPMailer Message";

$mail->Body = "Hi! \n\n This was sent with phpMailer_example3.php.";

if (!$mail->Send()) {

    echo 'Message was not sent.';

    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {

    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

After the run it is showing:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message was not sent.Mailer error:
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. SMTP server error:

were is the error??

Answer (score 0):

The error returned by PHP Mailer is usually accurate so make sure that you use the right credentials for the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe username is sumthing, not sumthing@yahoo.com ?
Also try first sending without SSL encryption, on normal SMTP port, if it works, you will know that problem is in SSL security.