# Trying to send mail using yahoo smtp in php

Tags: php

Please can some one suggest me codes to send mails using yahoo smatp, and php..

```
require("class.phpmailer.php"); // be sure to change this to your location!

$mail = new PHPMailer();    
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier    

$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; // sets yahoo as the SMTP server    
$mail->Port = 25; // set the SMTP port    
$mail->Username = "sumthing@yahoo.com"; // yahoo username    
$mail->Password = "password"; // yahoo password

$mail->From = "sumthing@yahoo.com";
$mail->FromName = "myname";    
$mail->AddAddress("you@example.com");    
$mail->Subject = "Test PHPMailer Message";    
$mail->Body = "Hi! \n\n This was sent with phpMailer_example3.php.";

if(!$mail->Send()) {

    echo 'Message was not sent.';    
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {

    echo 'Message has been sent.';

}
```

This code is giving me errrors 'Could not connect to SMTP host".

Comment: You should note that old Yahoo Mail (@yahoo.com) addresses do not support SMTP... You have to buy their premium options to support SMTP. But the new y7mail supports SMTP without having to buy a premium plan.

Comment: 3rd in a row duplicate of [want to send mails from php using yahoo smtp.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512204/want-to-send-mails-from-php-using-yahoo-smtp)

Comment: Believe it or not, it's actually the 5th time poulami has asked some variant of this question, Colonel.

Comment: i tried the y7mail too. but the problem remains...

Comment: @sharpnel  no solutions found till now..

Comment: I solved my problem.. thanxx... @ranihiru y7mail worked.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the sites providing SMTP do not support SSL (SMTP-S). If supported is usually in different port, such as 465. Connecting to 465 often fails. Try commenting out

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"
```

Try also first without authentication to make sure the connection works.